# How to interpret two variables in one inequality?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I know this might not be the best question to ask here but I haven't been able to find an explanation online.

Can someone tell me how to interpret this inequality:

`0 <= y <= x <= 1`

I don't know how to graph that? Do you first graph `y = x`? Then for the limits is this the case:

`0 <= y <= 1` and `0 <= x <= 1`

Comment: close,  It breaks apart into  $y\le x, x\le 1, y\ge 0$ and the last one, $x\ge0$ turns out to be unnecessary.

Comment: $0\leq y\leq x\leq 1$ implies all of the pairs: $0\leq y, 0\leq x, 0\leq 1, y\leq x, y\leq 1, x\leq 1$.  Some are redundant.  How you choose to center/focus your graph is up to you, but to contain the most relevant information, it should include $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ and should probably contain a bit more besides in each direction.  The resulting feasible set appears as a filled triangle with vertices $(0,0),(0,1),(1,1)$

Comment: @1290 sorry $y\ge 0$

Comment: Here is what the region is going to look like: [Graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/elcyhlhzih)

Comment: @DougM Ohh ok I see now thank you!

Comment: @Mitch Thank you for the graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just means that $0\leq y$ and $y\leq x$ and $x\leq 1$. By the transitivity of $\leq$ it follows that also $y\leq 1$ and $0\leq x$. Hence, a triangle shaped area is described.

Comment: So technically that is the same as y ≤ x, 0 ≤ y ≤ 1, and 0 ≤ x ≤ 1 right?

Comment: Yes, that is equivalent.

Comment: Okay it makes sense now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are certainly on the right track. It is indeed true that both $0 \le x \le 1$ and $0 \le y \le 1$. There is merely an extra condition imposed that $y \le x$ for all values of $x$. If you draw the line $y = x$ on a graph between $0$ and $1$, every point below the line corresponds to $y < x$. Therefore the region in question is just the right triangle with side length and base $1$ and the right angle at the bottom right corner of the graph.

Comment: If the inequality had y >= x would that be all the points above the line y = x?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Picture drawing a point on the line $y=x $, and then displacing it slightly upward. By doing this, you increase $y$, but leave $x$ fixed. Since you were just on a point where $y=x $, this implies that you are now at a value where $y>x$.